# Understanding Rails ActveRecord Associations: Class method called on result of where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have an example of using a `has_many_through` association that I'm trying to understand.

Suppose that there are classes (subclasses of `ActiveRecord::Base`) `Movie` and `Theater` and a third class `Showing` that records the association between them (what movies are showing at which theaters). The implementation of `Showing` is

```
class Showing < ActiveRecord::Base
   def self.movies
     Movie.where( id: pluck(:movie_id) )
   end

   def self.theaters
     Theater.where( id: pluck(:theater_id) )
   end
end
```

The class `Movie`

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    def showings
        Showing.where(movie_id: id)
    end

    def theaters
        showings.theaters
    end
end
```

This works, but I don't understand why. `theaters` is a class method on the class `Showing`, which returns all theaters that are showing somewhere. `showings` is an instance method, so that if `movie` is of class `Movie`, then `movie.showings` should return a set of objects of class `Showing`. So how does it make sense to write the following?

```
movie.showings.theaters
```

When I try it out, it correctly returns those theaters where that movie is showing, but since `theaters` is a class method, how does it make sense to call it on whatever is returned by `movies.showings`?

Answer (score 1):

`movie.showings` returns an ActiveRecord collection of `Showing` objects. The class methods you wrote, like `self.theaters` can be invoked by any ActiveRecord relation of `Showing` objects. `Showing.theaters` is similar to `movie.showings.theaters`, except in the second example, the `Showing` objects are just scoped to those that have an association with the given `movie`.

Another way to think about ActiveRecord class methods is that they operate on collections of records, whereas instance methods operate on single records.

Comment: Thanks, that answers it, but it seems like different behavior than the usual class methods.